# woocommerce_api_missing_product_data Error After Updating Woo Commerce Version 2.5.5 to 3.2.6

Tags: json, rest, api

I am integrating product posting with woo commerce using Rest Api.
I have done that posting through the legacy version of Woo Commerce V3 but it has been deprecated so I am unable to post the variation products.

Deprecation documentation:
[image: deprecated documentation detail]

On Legacy Version i am using these versions of Woo and Wp.

```
WC = 2.5.5
WP = 4.5.12
```

For Latest Rest Api's i have updated Woo Version to 3.2.6.
Now I get back to the latest version api V2 for product posting but I am facing that issue on every hit. In fact, I have posted the Same documented json for creating simple product.

Api Detail: /wp-json/wc/v2/products

```
{    
  "errors": [    
    {    
      "code": "woocommerce_api_authentication_error",    
      "message": "oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"    
    }    
  ]    
}
```

You can see the image for better understanding. I am using postman for that.

[image: Error code ocurred on product posting through postman]

If I post through code it gives me a 400 bad request error in the Api response.

[image: Api hit through Code:400 bad request error]